# Convert from US to UK format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I modify the following to be D/M/YYYY?

```
8/7/20 6:20 PM

8/17/20 4:24 PM
```

Currently it is M/D/YY

Here is what I have done to no avail:

1. =VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)-1)) - This is to extract the date portion (because excel sees it as text)
2. Tried to convert the date to a D/M/Y using 'text to columns' but that does not work. Excel sees the middle number as the date so anything over 12 and it throws an error.

Thank for any help on this. It's breaking me.

Comment: Usually, the best way to handle this is to correct the issue that resulted in the dates being entered incorrectly. That frequently is the result of incorrectly importing CSV or other textual data.  The problem with converting what you have is that, if they have been entered incorrectly, some will be text strings, and others will be "real" dates, but will have been converted incorrectly.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control how the data is formatted. But I have to clean it up for use in excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TEXT(A1,"d/m/yy")&" ",FIND(" ",TEXT(A1,"d/m/yy")&" ")-1),"/","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&{2,1,3}&"]"))+MID(TEXT(A1,"\ hh:mm AM/PM"),FIND(" ",TEXT(A1,"\ hh:mm AM/PM"))+1,99)
```

and then format the output as desired.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Note: I am US based so I had to reverse it in the demo.

Another Note:  If one is US based dealing with UK dates then change the `d/m/yy` to `m/d/yy` and it will work.

---

With Office 365

```
=LET(
    z,TEXT(A1,"d/m/y")&" ",
    y,LEFT(z,FIND(" ",z)),
    x,TEXT(A1,"\ hh:mm AM/PM"),
    q,MID(x,FIND(" ",x)+1,20),
    TEXTJOIN("/",,CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(y,"/"),2,1,3))+IFERROR(q,0))
```

[image]