# How to sort a column in excel which consists both date and time?

Tags: excel, date, sorting, time

I want to sort the date and time by latest record entered.
I saw that it was in text format.
Please see the below example:

```
Date Completed
10/08/2020 16:48:11
02/06/2019 15:45:13
05/06/2020 20:10:45
23/09/2018 17:46:40
20/01/2020 03:50:12
19/10/2019 04:25:46
```

Thanks.

Comment: If your dates are numbers stored as text, the best method would be to use TEXT-To-columns to do the conversion to real dates, then it is just a matter of sorting descending.

Comment: and if it is a matter of your local date/time being `mm/dd/yyyy` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy` then see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581292/convert-from-us-to-uk-format making sure to see the note at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: The date is already in text format, I tried to convert it to long date and tried to sort but it shows A to Z or Z to A on the sort. i think it should show oldest to newest and newest to oldest.

Comment: then you need to convert it to a true date.  Use Text-To-Columns.  Just because it looks like a date does not mean it is recognized as on to Excel

Comment: You will know its a date when you use this formula on a date cell and it returns true:  'ISNUMBER(A3)'  Where A3 is the cell you are testing

Comment: I think easiest way would be using a helper column, with VAL function, to convert those dates into numeric values, and then sort from max (latest) to min (oldest)

Comment: can you please elaborate on helper column and VAL functions. Because I tried =Value(10/09/2018 19:30:45) and it gave me error(#VALUE!)