# US dates getting converted to UK format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got an excel dataset which has a date column. My system date format is set to US which is `MM-DD-YYYY`. Our team over in UK uses the UK format, i.e., `DD-MM-YYYY`.

So when the dataset is transferred to a template, certain dates for example `10-Dec-2021 (12-10-2021 MM-DD-YYYY)` gets changed to `12-Oct-2021 (12-10-2021 DD-MM-YYYY)` for the UK folks.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Change your format to `yyyy-mm-dd`  It will then transfer correctly no matter the source or target settings

Comment: if you want a formula to do it on the back end: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581292/convert-from-us-to-uk-format

Comment: If @ScottCraner idea is not appropriate for your work setting, please provide more information.  Excel stores dates as serial numbers (`1/1/1900 = 1`) and the format is merely how that value is displayed.  If you are storing your date strings as text, you may need to change that.  If you are using CSV files, you will need to import rather than open the files.

Comment: Better yet, don't store dates as strings.  Store them as DateTime serial numbers, and use format to display them as you want