# Convert text to specific date

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following text in cell A1
09-03-22
that's mm-dd-yyyy

the type is general but I want to Convert it into Date with the format dd.mm.yyyy
Can be in Excel or with vba....
Because if I change the type to date it always returns as 09.03.2022 or 09 March 2022 ... Excel thinks my month is my day and the other way around. But what I want is 03.09.2022

Comment: If **all the existing Date in that range are converted in the same way "mm-dd-yyy"**, you can do something to reconvert, but I think that most probably the Date in discussion have been imported as string/Text and Excel converted it as Date just guessing which to be the day/month. Usually, for the cases where day and month are less than 12, it converts according to the default date format of your system. So, if you place in a next cell a formula `Day(A2)`, supposing that the respective range is in A:A column, does it consistently return the real day **for all the cases**?

Comment: @FaneDuru I get the following:

for the text 09-03-22 I'm getting  9 and for every number above 12 like the date 09-13-22 I get #VALUE

Comment: @FaneDuru do you know, is it maybe possible to save the text in vba as a string and say that the format is mm-dd-yyyy and change the format to dd-mm-yyyy and put the right date in the cell above?

Comment: @ALeXceL I also tried it like this but it only works for dates <12 like 09-03-22

Comment: I am afraid you cannot do any automation in this moment. Where from did you import the column in discussion? If you still have the respective file, depending on the file type it can be possible to import it as text (the column in discussion) and then consistently convert to date. **Only after that choose what format you want**...

Comment: @loons Ok I deleted my comment as I realized the value is in the General format... Sorry.

Comment: This is doable with `MID` and `DATE` worksheet formulas, or `Mid` and `DateSerial` in VBA.

Comment: @FaneDuru it's a huge file with many different informations... I get the whole file as an xlsx file. After that I look for the "dates" and have to get the weeknr from each date e.g 08-13-22 is week33 08-20-22 week34 and so on....then I write the weeknr in the next cell. I wanted to do it with a Macro because before and after this step there are many other steps that are completed by the same macro...

Comment: Select your column >> Text-To-Columns on the data tab >> Fixed width >> Choose Date in MDY format and hit ok. Format the column as desired. In your case `dd.mm.yyyy`.

Comment: `=--TEXTJOIN("-",TRUE,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(TEXT(A1,"d-m-yy"),"-"),{3,1,2}))`

Comment: @ScottCraner While TEXTJOIN is there from some time now, TEXTSPLIT is still only available to Office Insider Beta program currently.

Comment: @VincentG I know that, That is why I did not answer but made a comment.

Comment: @VincentG here is a version that uses FILTERXML instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581292/convert-from-us-to-uk-format

Answer (score 0):

With VBA, this is one way to do it in the ActiveCell:

```
Sub TxtDateToDate()

    Dim strDate As String

    With ActiveCell
        strDate = .Value
        strDate = Split(strDate, ".")(1) & "/" & _
            Split(strDate, ".")(0) & "/" & _
            Split(strDate, ".")(2)
        .Formula = .Value + 0 'shake cell format
        .Formula = DateValue(strDate)
        .NumberFormat = "MM.DD.YYYY"
    End With
  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your case, it looks that there is a column having inconsistent `Date`/`String` data. The existing `Date` swaps the day with month and the string date starts with month followed by day.

If this is the case, please try the next code. It assumes that the column to be processed is A:A, and returns in column B:B. You can easily change the two columns:

```
Sub ConvertText_DateToDate()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrD, arrStrD, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value2
  ReDim arrD(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If IsNumeric(arr(i, 1)) Then
            arrD(i, 1) = DateSerial(Year(arr(i, 1)), Day(arr(i, 1)), Month(arr(i, 1)))
        Else
            arrStrD = Split(arr(i, 1), "/")
            arrD(i, 1) = DateSerial(CLng(arrStrD(2)), CLng(arrStrD(0)), CLng(arrStrD(1)))
        End If
  Next i
  'format and drop the processed array content, at once:
  With sh.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arrD), 1)
        .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
        .Value2 = arrD
  End With
End Sub
```

But, if the `Date` part did not swap day with month, you have to use

```
   arrD(i, 1) = arr(i, 1)
```

Instead of:

```
    arrD(i, 1) = DateSerial(Year(arr(i, 1)), Day(arr(i, 1)), Month(arr(i, 1)))
```