# Is there a way to convert excel cell entries to a consistent date and time format?

Tags: excel, date, format

I am processing some rain gauge data from a csv file generated by the data logger of the gauge. I have found that the date and time are being logged inconsistently, appearing interchangeably in either of the following two formats:

```
Format 1) mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm         (24 hour clock)
```

or

```
Format 2) mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss AM/PM  (12 hour clock)
```

This is a problem inherent to the gauge and I do not have access to its software to any make modifications.

IMPORTANTLY: I am designing a tutorial for non-scientists to collect and process this data without assistance. They have no coding experience so need to figure out a way of getting these date formats consistent in MS excel alone, preprogrammed so they can plug and play, so to speak.

I have imported via Excel>Get Data> From Text, setting the format of the date column as MDY. It appears that the rows with Format 1 are correctly registered as dates, however, Format 2 is not being recognised, and instead is only recognised as text (I think). The dataset looks a bit like this:

```
01/31/22 03:59:48 PM          71
01/31/22 08:30:08 PM          71.2
01/31/22 08:31:28 PM          71.4
     02/01/2022  02:57:00     71.6
     02/01/2022  02:58:00     71.8
     02/01/2022  02:59:00     72
```

I have tried various methods, such as =VALUE(), and =DATEVALUE(), but these only return a VALUE error. Is there a way for me to convert Format 2 entries to Format 1?

Again, unfortunately, I do not have the means to alter the way the datalogger records the data...

Comment: What is the source? why is it in two different formats? Why not correct the source?

Comment: Actually the first three rows are interpreted as text and rows 4-6 are converted to true dates and times. This is because Excel assumes your date order is d/m/y but the data is in m/d/y. You should use open Excel first and then use Data, Get Data, From CSV to import the file. You can then set that date column to the correct format. See: https://jkp-ads.com/articles/importtext.asp

Comment: or if you want a formula to do the conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581292/convert-from-us-to-uk-format

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have imported using the get data from csv and set the MDY date format, this is still an issue. (I'll add an edit to the question)

Comment: The source is a data logger that I do not have access to, so I cannot make the corrections myself

Comment: ***I have imported using the get data from csv*** You probably need to set the correct culture in the Power Query editor. Edit your question to include a data sample showing the problem **as text which can be copy/pasted**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dates are stored in column A with an header in cell A1, you can use this formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(DAY(A2)),DATE(MID(A2,7,2)+2000,MID(A2,1,2),MID(A2,4,2))+TIME(MID(A2,10,2)+IF(RIGHT(A2,2)="PM",12,0),MID(A2,13,2),MID(A2,16,2)),A2)
```

Still, the values might still return you an error in specific dates like 3rd of march or 10th of july or basically any first 12 days of each month. Assuming you are manually pasting these data, you might set the format of column A as text, then paste the data and the use the formula; although only part of it would be really necessary, like:

```
=DATE(MID(A2,7,2)+2000,MID(A2,1,2),MID(A2,4,2))+TIME(MID(A2,10,2)+IF(RIGHT(A2,2)="PM",12,0),MID(A2,13,2),MID(A2,16,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

After you `Get Data => From Text/CSV` you probably see a window like this:

[image]

Select `Transform Data`

Then select the Date column and, from the Right Click Menu select `Change Type Using Locale` =>

[image]

In the dialog that opens, select

```
Data Type: Date/Time
```

and

```
Locale: English (United States)
```

[image]

Then `Close & Load` from the File menu and you should be good to go.