# change date in excel from MDY to DMY

Tags: excel

I have a column in excel open in power query that has dates. the format is m/d/yy hh:mm;@. example :1/3/2023 6:00:00 AM. this is considered as January 3rd. I want to change it to be march, meaning I want the 3 to be the month and 1 to be the day, so it becomes 1st march.

I made sure the column is of type date, I went to "text to column" and switched it from MDY to DMY and I also tried to switch the text formats with this : =TEXT(A2, "dd/m/yy hh:mm;@") and then converting it to date type, but nothing worked

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581292/convert-from-us-to-uk-format

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Essentially you want to format your text date in a way that switches the month and day around, and then use `DATEVALUE()` to turn it back into an actual date value.

```
 =DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1, "YYYY-DD-MM"))
```

Comment: Hello, so this worked, but the values that were over the number 12 (which is being taken as month) have given an error, like for example 13/3/2023 gave '#VALUE!'. it's still sort of considering 13 as the month and 3 as the day for these, but worked fine for the dates under 13

Comment: What would you want it to do in that case? I can't even begin to guess.